# Java - Split and get the needed string from the string

Tags: java, split

i have a string like the following `[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;`

how to get the string `com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO` this only from `[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;` in java. there are few cases where i get `com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;` so i also have to check whether the given string has the format of what i am expecting like `com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO`

Please help me to correct it.

Comment: if it has a predictable pattern you can use REGEX, and please provide a snippet of code that you've tried

Comment: Please, clarify your requisites because it's hard to understand what do you want to do

Comment: What you're seeing is (I believe) the String representation of an object of type `com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO` contained in an array. So check for array and get the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code:

```
String toBeFixed = "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;"; 
String toReplaceWith =toBeFixed.replaceAll("\\[L", "").replaceAll("\\;","");
System.out.println(toReplaceWith);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a regex:

```
String input = "com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO"; //OR "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[L)*([\\w\\.]+)(\\;)*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the string com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO this only from [Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;

```
String res = str.substring(2,str.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work in your case, considering you have string replacement query:

```
public void test(){
String s1 = "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO";
String s2 = "com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO";
System.out.println(getClassName(s1));  
System.out.println(getClassName(s2));
}

public String getClassName(String s){
            if(s.startsWith("\\[L")){
                s = s.substring(2, s.length()-1);
            }
      return s;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use substring function
String url="com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO";
int n=url.length();
String url1=url.substring(
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.